# Map list of JSON to Tabbar flutter

Tags: json, flutter, mapping, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

I'm trying to map list of json to tab bar, and want tab bar title as "JSON1"

`API response :"data": [{"JSON1": {"key1": "val1","key2": "val2"}}],`

My code :
     `List dataResponse =  [{JSON1: {key1: val1, key2: val2}}]; TabBar( tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start, indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab, dividerColor: Theme.of(context).dividerColor, controller: _tabController, indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary, labelColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary, unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark.withOpacity(0.8), isScrollable: Responsive.isDesktop(context) ? true : true, tabs: dataResponse.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(), );`
`

Getting error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type JsonMap

Comment: Would you please show more context about the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You received the error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type JsonMap because you are sending the whole json in the Text widget of dataResponse.map((**e**) => Text(**e**)).toList()

> where **e** = ({"JSON1": {"key1": "val1","key2": "val2"}})

instead, send only

> "Json1"

To resolve the above issue, replace your code from

```
dataResponse.map((e) => Text(e)).toList()
```

with the following in tabs:

```
dataResponse.map((e) => Text(e.keys.first)).toList()
```

This code iterates through the list and finds the first key from each json map of the list. here first key is Json1 so you'll receive output as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
List dataResponse = [{"JSON1": {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}}];

TabBar(
  tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
  dividerColor: Theme.of(context).dividerColor,
  controller: _tabController,
  indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
  labelColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
  unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark.withOpacity(0.8),
  isScrollable: Responsive.isDesktop(context) ? true : true,
  tabs: dataResponse.map((e) {
    // Extract the title (assuming there's only one key in the JSON map)
    String title = e.keys.first;
    return Tab(text: title);
  }).toList(),
);
```